# Zimbra certbot LetsEncrypt - verification failure - expecting an RSA key

Tags: email, certbot

Zimbra Certbot LetsEncrypt

I have installed a LetsEncrypt SSL certificate on a separate server for a different domain without problems.

I followed the same procedures that I used on that server for a new server (Ubuntu Server - same as the other) and everything worked up until the verification.

```
** Verifying '/opt/zimbra/ssl/letsencrypt/cert.pem' against '/opt/zimbra/ssl/zimbra/commercial/commercial.key'

140072965674304:error:0607907F:digital envelope routines:EVP_PKEY_get0_RSA:expecting an rsa key:crypto/evp/p_lib.c:474:

ERROR: Certificate '/opt/zimbra/ssl/letsencrypt/cert.pem' and private key '/opt/zimbra/ssl/zimbra/commercial/commercial.key' do not match.
```

I have not been able to find any information on how to fix this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.  In the open source 8.8.15 version of Zimbra (I don't know if it is still a problem for the version 9 paid program), Zimbra does not understand the ECDSA type SSL keys.  The code is specifically looking for a RSA key and if it is not a RSA key then will fail the verification, even though the verification is actually good.

Therefore, if using this version of Zimbra, you need to specify the key-type = RSA when making a SSL key request from Let's Encrypt (and probably other providers).

Unfortunately it took a long time with misleading information (ie. keys don't match) to figure this out.  Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe your certificate would be upgraded to ECDSA so need to renew your certificate with RSA.

Use this command to renew

```
certbot certonly --standalone -d {your domain} --force-renewal --preferred-chain "ISRG Root X1" --key-type rsa
```

Root Account

```
cd /etc/letsencrypt/live/{domain}/
cat isrgrootx1.pem.txt letsencryptauthorityx3.pem.txt chain.pem > combined.pem
cp * /opt/zimbra/ssl/letsencrypt/
chown zimbra:zimbra /opt/zimbra/ssl/letsencrypt/*
```

Zimbra Account

```
cd /opt/zimbra/ssl/letsencrypt/
cp /opt/zimbra/ssl/letsencrypt/privkey.pem /opt/zimbra/ssl/zimbra/commercial/commercial.key
/opt/zimbra/bin/zmcertmgr verifycrt comm privkey.pem cert.pem combined.pem
/opt/zimbra/bin/zmcertmgr deploycrt comm cert.pem combined.pem
```